Connect to multiple aws accounts using ARN" in python
Friends,
I need help in "Connect to multiple aws accounts using ARN" in python, got below link for reference.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_cross-account-with-roles.html#tutorial_cross-account-with-roles-1.
